# how to make button color variable in xml/java (android studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, button

I am very very sorry if this question is too broad to answer in specific code, but i am just starting out and want to know how to tackle a specific function.
I have been trying to set a buttons xml color as a variable the same way that i am setting it below, where i set the button id in my layout to the variable Team1button then use that to set its text.

Team1button = findViewById(R.id.button);

String Teamname = "tree";

Team1button.setText(Teamname);

Essentially i want to do the same thing as .setText, but with color because i am wanting color to change through other events happening in my code. In the end i want it to be the user choosing the color of each button, but that is a different question i will answer myself after being able to make the buttons color changeable in either xml or java. If you know what type of function i would need to do in either my layout files or my .java files it would be greatly appreciated if you gave me any input on how to do this. This is for school project.

Comment: what exactly you want , change color of button by event @Blake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Button class documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Basically, if I understend you correctly you want to call :

```
button.setBackgroundColor(int colorID);
```

e.g.

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: It turns out i had been misusing the function previously, and trying to do it all through the xml not the java files. Just have to use if statements for the user input part. Thank you so much!